# Where can I get a SQL Server Trace Dataset?

Tags: sql-server, profiler, trace-flags

I need a huge SQL Server query trace file (like the profiler trace) with the SQL query text and the time-stamp. I need a trace of SQL traffic produced by a real application because I want to do some pattern analysis. I check many online dataset sites, but I couldn't find one. I don't think anyone will set a profiler trace in production environment since it reduces the performance. But I need a huge trace file (or just SQL Text and Time-stamp will be enough) with the database (with schema and data). Is it possible to get such a data-set ?

At least is it possible to find a data-set with 24 hours of trace?
Does Microsoft has trace files for it's sample databases such as AdventureWorks?

Answer (score 1):

Pattern analysis would be entirely dependent on workload.

Every workload is different. Not just differences between transactional (OLTP) and analytics (OLAP), but even a dozen OLTP applications will produce entirely different patterns.

If you want to build a synthetic one, capture a trace while benchmark tests run. You can start with Benchmark Factory or HammerDB as [mentioned in this Stack answer.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74971/how-to-benchmark-microsoft-sql-server)

Comment: Any workload is OK as far as it has some patterns, I just need one workload for analysis, but I don't have a huge high traffic database to set up a trace, that's why I am looking for somewhere else.